# Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 not detected

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers, asus, atheros

I am currently dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Suddenly the wifi adapter is not detected on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I tried to check for the adapter using `rfkill` and `lspci` but no such Network Controller appeared, but Ethernet Controller does. What is the best way to solve this? Do I need to update/reinstall the driver? My system is Asus Vivobook.

Comment: This feels like a hardware issue. Can you see anything in dmesg about the wifi adapter at all? If not then perhaps try re-seating (is it a built-in adapter or external)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried ```demsg```  but itdoes not return anything about the adapter and it is a built-in adapter.